# vs2010 freezes on validating web site forever

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I converted from VS2008 to VS2010.
when I build the solution it gets frozen on validating web site, and it was frozen for a few minutes on a dll build.

it won't complete!

what can be the problem?

thanks

Comment: Have you installed the VS2010 Service Pack? It was freezing on many things here before we installed the Service Pack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validating step does a number of things.  It checks your web.config file to make sure it is correct and then checks the .aspx files to make sure they are properly written.  I would check the web.config file since this is a likely choice for errors during the conversion.

Also you can get a dump of the debug info by following the directions here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikhailarkhipov/archive/2007/09/19/how-to-obtain-debug-information-from-a-hung-frozen-application.aspx

this could help you find out whats wrong

Comment: Thanks. web.config must have been corrupted